# Updating ArcGIS Online feature service Layer Error with FME?

Tags: arcgis-online, fme-form

I am having issues updating a feature service with Safe FME. I looked up the example model and as far as I can tell I am following it. It seems to be running most of the model and throws an error as it starts trying to update the Feature Service. I am not sure what the issue is. I set the Feature Layer to allow edits. I have the reader for the ArcGIS Feature Layer and the Reader for the shapefile source, also the FeatureMerger to add the FID Field to the update table. 
LOG: http://pastebin.com/U1Hu06GS

[image]

Comment: Line 47 of your error shows: `Python Exception <HTTPError>: 404 Client Error: Not Found`.  Do you have any python code running?  Perhaps as a python parameter or shutdown script? If so, can you please edit your post to show it?

Comment: I do not have any Python running, I am guessing it is something on ArcGIS onlines processes. That is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out what the issue was. I had to add the ArcGIS Online Reader for the existing Feature Layer before adding the ArcGIS Online writer. Then I had to copy the "Layer Definition" from the previously added ArcGIS Online reader for that Feature Layer. Then it worked as expected.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar situation attempting to write to AGOL hosted tables.  Was getting error 403 (You do not have permissions to access this resource or perform this operation).  I tried about every permutation of connection configuration I could think of, but no love.  However, when I added a Reader to the AGOL feature service, it started working, even though Reader is not really involved in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Whats interesting is there actually is a bug for this with Arc online:

ESRI Error:

https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDExNTI1Mw==
https://community.esri.com/thread/206364-intermittent-504-gateway-timeouts-with-hosted-feature-layers#

FME error:
https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/65240/request-timed-out-in-arcgis-online.html